# 500 error : Unable to get required configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore'

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-server, iis-10

I have an internal server error at my .NET Core web service launch. Tuesday morning, the web-service was lauching well, Tuesday afternoon a windows update has been installed (KB4570720 package), Wednesday I have this 500 error...

The IIS error page tell me :

- Module          AspNetCoreModuleV2
- Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
- Gestionnaire    aspNetCore
- Code d'erreur   0x80004005

And IIS log event has this specific error :

> Could not load configuration. Exception message: Unable to get required configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore'. Possible reason is web.config authoring error.

This my web.config, I don't see what's wrong.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="aspNetCore" />
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\loemail.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
           <environmentvariables />
        </aspNetCore>
            <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

- I have tried to change the encoding from UTF8 to ANSI.
- I've tried to change the stdoutLogEnabled from false to true but there is no error there since it occurs before.
- I've tried to remove completely the web.config and copy-paste the one from my backup.
- I've tried to reinstall the web-service.

I have another .NET Core application running on this server, so I excluded issues with the .NET framework version but maybe I'm wrong? How could I check that? Both use .NET Framework 2.2.

Should I remove the last windows update package?

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem by copy/paste the web.config from my other application... And I still see no difference between them ! Computer makes us crazy sometimes...